# Efficient way to know if shape intersects with nodes in 2d node array libgdx?

Tags: java, android, optimization, libgdx

I have created an A Star search algorithm (A*) and I want to know which nodes a polygon shape is currently intersecting. The nodes array is the entire path finding grid (eg 200 x 200). I know I could loop through all of the nodes and test for collision against the polygon, but that would be far to inefficient. Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't use box2d? you can create a polygon object with the node position info and handle collision easily in an much more efficient way than  iterate nodes every frame..

Comment: @Hllink My game's physics is very simple, so I decided not to go with box2d.

Comment: why not use it even for a simple game, if it's assured that that lib will give you the most performance you can get and it's lightweight? just curious.. For your question you could divide the polygon into triangles objects, handling the intersect in each triangle, you will get more performance with multiple objects colliding instead one big polygon intersecting objects.. [Just take a look at this:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation)